Swaps hedged curves and butterflies strategies
I want to try to trade Butterflies/Curves strategies on sofr swaps. These strategies will be mean reverting. My idea is as follow for the 5-10-30 butterfly:

I run a regression between the swap rates $C_i$ without an intercept: $C_{10} = \beta_1 \cdot C_5 + \beta_2 \cdot C_{30} +\epsilon$.

To be fully hedged, I construct the following position: $N \cdot \left( 2\times\text{10y SWAP} - \beta_1 \cdot \frac{DV01_{10}}{DV01_{5}} \cdot \text{30y SWAP} 
- \beta_2 \cdot \frac{DV01_{10}}{DV01_{30}} \cdot \text{5y SWAP} \right)
$


where $N$ is a dollar notional and where $DV01_i$ is the DV01 of the swap $i$.
The idea is that if the above position is positive, it suggests mean reversion, so I would short the position; otherwise, I would go long. Essentially, I'm trading the residual

ϵ from the regression.
I'm wondering:

Is this a good way to hedge the position? (or PCA shows better mean reverting patterns?)
Are there better ways to approach this?
Additionally, does anyone have experience running similar mean-reverting strategies? Specifically, does the residual $\epsilon$ ever get significantly large, indicating that the correlation has "broken"? I would love to hear about potential pitfalls or lessons from those who have traded these kinds of strategies.


But why 5-10-30 rather than, for example, 2-5-10? Does looking at the actual PC3 support that?

I'd ask, why are you regressing overlapping intervals. When I think of the richness of 5s vs 2s, I'd surely want to understand 2y fwd 3y dynamics etc. The reason is (feel free to openly dispute), I like to work with fairly disconnected variables (I.e. where x doesn't connect x+y). Whenever someone is connecting x with x+y, it feels like ultimately you are seeing a relationship which is by definition...

The strategy you mention is reasonable.  (I don’t think you need the 2 in the formula).  In my experience this works well when the market is relatively rangebound , so that the regression residual represents short term supply and demand. It works less well when there is a larger move caused by a fundamental change in the market.  The holding period for these trades is usually days/weeks rather than months, I would say.
